# Spark - reducing input file by user Id

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working with a structured input file that contains userId, seqId, eventType and country. I need to reduce it by userId taking the last non-empty value of each field after ordering by seqId. For the given input:

```
userId    seqId eventType country
A1600001    2   Update  JP
A1600001    3   Update  
B2301001    2   Update  CH
A1600001    1   Create  CH
C1200011    2   Update  
C1200011    1   Create  IN
```

The reduced result should be:

```
A1600001    3   Update  JP
C1200011    2   Update  IN
B2301001    2   Update  CH
```

I started with the following:

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("/tmp/sample-events.tsv")
scala> val lines = file.map( x => (x.split("\t")(0), x) )
scala> lines.foreach(x => println(x))
(A1600001,A1600001  2   Update  JP)
(A1600001,A1600001  3   Update  )
(B2301001,B2301001  2   Update  CH)
(A1600001,A1600001  1   Create  CH)
(C1200011,C1200011  2   Update  )
(C1200011,C1200011  1   Create  IN)
```

Now I want to `reduceByKey` lines (I guess?), but I'm pretty new to the subject and I don't know how to construct the reduction function. Can someone help?

Comment: Quick question, do you want to use RDD for this transformation or do you want to use more recent ways. Using RDD in spark nowadays is not recommended. But if you are doing by learning reasons I could help. So your limitation is to do this with RDD? Or can we use DataSets?

Comment: as @ThiagoBaldim said using DataSets/DataFrames will be much simpler (and more efficient most probably)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the DataSets approach. We can use DataSets.

Comment: seqid has no gap i assume?

Comment: There can be gaps. But it's an ever increasing integer.

Comment: Have you solved this? Try dataframes

Comment: Progress? If not I will post a solution tonight. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Using spark-sql and window functions.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("A1600001",2,"Update","JP"),("A1600001",3,"Update",""),("B2301001",2,"Update","CH"),("A1600001",1,"Create","CH"),("C1200011",2,"Update",""),("C1200011",1,"Create","IN")).toDF("userId","seqId","eventType","country")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [userId: string, seqId: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("samsu")

scala> spark.sql(""" with tb1(select userId, seqId, eventType, country, lag(country) over(partition by userid order by seqid) lg1, row_number() over(partition by userid order by seqid) rw1,co
unt(*) over(partition by userid) cw1 from samsu) select userId, seqId, eventType,case when country="" then lg1 else country end country from tb1 where rw1=cw1 """).show(false)
+--------+-----+---------+-------+                                              
|userId  |seqId|eventType|country|
+--------+-----+---------+-------+
|A1600001|3    |Update   |JP     |
|C1200011|2    |Update   |IN     |
|B2301001|2    |Update   |CH     |
+--------+-----+---------+-------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way (assuming that `seqId` is never empty):

1. prepare `pair_rdd1` by filtering out all empty `eventType` values with mapper first, then apply `reduceByKey` on key=`userId` to find latest non-empty `eventType` per `userId`. Assuming the reducer function takes two `[seqId, eventType]` pairs and returns `[seqId, eventType]` pair, reduce function should look like: `(v1 v2) => ( if(v1[seqId] > v2[seqId]) then v1 else v2 )`
2. prepare `pair_rdd2` by filtering out all empty `country` values with mapper first, then apply `reduceByKey` on key=`userId` to find latest non-empty `country` per `userId`. Assuming the reducer function takes two `[seqId, country]` pairs and returns `[seqId, country]` pair, reduce function should look like: `(v1 v2) => ( if(v1[seqId] > v2[seqId]) then v1 else v2 )`
3. since we need the latest `seqId` per `userId` as well, we prepare `pair_rdd3` by applying `reduceByKey` on key=`userId` and reducer function: `(seqId1 seqId2) => max(seqId1, seqId2)`
4. now we perform `pair_rdd3.leftOuterJoin(pair_rdd1)` to get `[userId, seqId, eventType]`, then on the result of left join we perform `.leftOuterJoin(pair_rdd2)` to finally get `[userId, seqId, eventType, country]` (both joins are on key=`userId`)

Note that we use `left join` instead of `inner join` here, since there could be user IDs with all eventTypes or all countries being empty

Comment: Can you clarify something for the step #2 above? How do you ensure that user A1600001 gets the country "JP", and not "CH"? The order should be determined by the seqId, not by the appearance. Do we need to order the data by seqId before applying reduceByKey? Note that userId, seqId and eventType are never empty.

Comment: @samsu, so after filtering out `A1600001    3   Update <empty country>`, we will have only `A1600001    1   Create  CH` and `A1600001    2   Update  JP`. hence reducer gets values `[1, CH]` and `[2, JP]` for user `A1600001`. it checks the `seqId` and because 2 is larger than 1, it is going to output `[A1600001, 2, JP]`.  note that we're doing joins at the end so nothing is lost here although we're filtering out the rows with missing values at the beginning

Comment: @thebluephantom this website is not necessarily code-assistive. I gave him a way to solve the problem by using `rdd`, which could be coded by using dozens of spark scala tutorials out there on the web

Comment: True but even for me hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that I can think of with ReduceByKey is here.

```
//0: userId    1: seqId  2: eventType 3: country
val inputRdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("data/input.txt")
  .map(_.split("\\s+", 4))

//Here reduce by userId and taking the record which is having max(seqId)
// order by seqId so that if the max value missing country, can be merged that value from the immediate seqId
inputRdd
  .map(ls => (ls(0), ls))
  .sortBy(_._2(1).toInt)
  .reduceByKey {
    (acc, y) =>
      if (acc(1).toInt < y(1).toInt)
        if (y.length == 3) y :+ acc(3) else y
      else
        acc
  }.map(_._2.mkString("\t"))
  .foreach(println)
```

*data/input.txt*

```
A1600001    2   Update  JP
A1600001    3   Update
B2301001    2   Update  CH
A1600001    1   Create  CH
C1200011    2   Update
C1200011    1   Create  IN
```

*Output:*

```
B2301001    2   Update  CH
C1200011    2   Update  IN
A1600001    3   Update  JP
```

Comment: you can't simply remove the rows if there's a value missing. for example, let's assume that `user1` has two rows only: 
`user1     1      Update                        <empty country>` and 
`user1      2     <empty eventType>    JP`. 
with your solution, both rows will be omitted, while the output should have:
`user1      2     Update      JP`

Comment: besides the OP wants to have the largest `seqId` per `userId`, and in your solution, the largest `seqId` has a risk to get skipped if there's a value missing.

Comment: in my opinion, it is not possible to solve this problem by a single reduce step (not with `rdd` at least)

Comment: I have solved as per this in the question `userId taking the last non-empty value of each field after ordering by seqId, and as per the example data we have only last field as emtpy.`

Comment: I can't simply filter out just because the row has a missing value. In the actual input data the first three columns can't be empty, but the last column (country) can be empty. There are several more columns like country in the data, but for this example "country" is the only optional column. Thus Bhima's output "A1600001    2   Update  JP" must be "A1600001    3   Update  JP" as in my posting.